# Android AudioInputStream

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm looking to open a file on a user's Android device ("song.mp3") and read the audio samples, much like an `AudioInputStream` in Java.  I also want the possibility of reading multiple file types (.wav, .mp3, etc) but if it only reads one file type that is fine.  I'm simply looking for ANY library that will allow me to read raw audio samples.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the [MediaCodec class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html).

Answer (score -3):

The `android.media` package has a range of various tools. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.html

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't read the android label. Please incluse your platform in your question next time :). Use `android.media.MediaPlayer`

Comment: Can you tell me how to get raw samples from `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: take a look at my updates awswer, the link should provide some help.

Comment: I don't want to play an MP3, I want to access the raw audio samples

Comment: I'm sorry, in that case i misunderstood your question. What exactly do you mean by raw audio samples?

Comment: I want to be able to access the audio samples that make up the audio file